# Single instrumentation tests can't be started from Android Studio (starting from Chipmunk)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-chipmunk

After updating Android Studio to Chipmunk we can't start our UI tests located in differen folder than androidTest from AndroidStudio itself anymore.

We get instead an error message:

```
Error running "...Test"
Class "..." not found in module 'OurApp:app'
```

As mentioned above our tests are not located in androidTest folder, but in **sharedTestDebug** instead. However it wasn't a problem with prior versions of Android Studio until Chipmunk.

We also add this folders in our **build.gradle**

```
sourceSets {
    String sharedTestDebugDir = 'src/sharedTestDebug/java'
    String sharedTestDir = 'src/sharedTest/java'
    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs += sharedTestDir
        java.srcDirs += sharedTestDebugDir
    }
}
```

Another finding: we are only not able to start single tests. if we start running all tests from AS, it works.

**update**

Also found out that in "Edit configurations" we are not able to select any instrumented test other then from **androidTest** folder

**update2**

same behavior in the dolphin and electric eel versions :(

if you want to run a single instrumented tests you need to select module to run the test from. Unfortunately in the selection you can only select the module with corresponding androidTest folder.

**update3**
It seems to be a known issue :(

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228392691

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to let run single instrumentation tests again

I created a symbol link referencing from the folder where our tests located to androidTestDebug. For that I ran following command from the src-folder:

```
ln -s sharedTestDebug androidTestDebug
```

To have it also in git I called

```
git ls-files -s ./app/src/androidTestDebug
```

and then

```
git add ./app/src/androidTestDebug
```

Maybe someone else will find another solution.